# Android studio unit test got stuck on "Debugger is waiting for application to Start" in debug mode

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm new in Android development, when running unit test case in debug mode, it got stuck on "Debugger is waiting for application to Start" however worked when running unit test without debug mode.

I tried the solution provided in the internet. restarting the studio, changing the edit configuration but nothing helped